# Django won't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

After spending hours finding the correct connectors to hook up MySQL with Django, I can't create a super user. Error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'
>   cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.\r\n")

I tried setting environment variables, `settings.configure()` which said the settings were already configured. db info is all correctly entered in `settings.py`.

Pycharm is able to connect to the db though, this is inside my django project and the db title in pycharm says Django default. I don't know if this means my Django project is connected to it but I just can't create a super user or that the pycharm connection is not related.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306
    }
}
```

When i try `django-admin dbshell`  I get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Both solutions provided in the error have had no positive result.

My last question got marked as duplicate although the solution didn't work, the question was also different in some ways.. anyway below is what happened when I tried using the legacy password security.

After re-migrating I got it working with the legacy authentication. Solutions for the newer and much more secure sha2 authentication would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you migrated your DB?

Comment: @JPQ I just tried re-migrating and it helped. Although I don't feel comfortable using the older password security. Do you maybe have possible solutions for the sha2 authentication?

Comment: Sorry... I have no idea about that

Answer (score 1):

Change your MySQL user password

```
ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';
```

Then put your password on Django settings file. Hope, this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use python 64-bit and install mysqlclint using `pip install mysqlclient` or `pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient` use space properly. This problem is occurred may be due to python 32-bit and mysql 64 bit and you have installed the mysqlclient using python extentions package.
If you are using mysql 64-bit then better use python 64-bit.